# Fixed width font - Symbian C++ CEikLabel

Tags: c++, fonts, symbian, s60, ceiklabel

I want to change the font I am using in a CEikLabel on S60 device

I believe I can do the following

```
const CFont* aPlainFont = LatinPlain12();
aLabel->SetFont(aPlainFont);
```

where LatinPlain12 is one from this list..

```
Albi12
Alp13
Alpi13
Albi13
alp17
Alb17b
albi17b
alpi17
Aco13
Aco21
Acalc21
LatinBold12
LatinBold13
LatinBold17
LatinBold19 
LatinPlain12
Acb14
Acb30
Acp5
```

However, who can help me find out which ones from this list are fixed width.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programatically, you can determine if a font is proportional using:

```
const CFont* myFont; 
// Initialize your font
// ....
TBool isProportional = (myFont->FontSpecInTwips().iTypeface.Attributes() & TTypeFace::EProportional);
```

BTW you might be better off enumerating the fonts on the device and/or using the logical font API than relying on the static font accessor functions.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [FontViewer](http://www.newlc.com/FontViewer.html) application to view and find out which of the fonts are proportional and fixed-width.

Comment: I cannot install this onto my N95 from http://www.newlc.com/files/FontViewer-S60.sis - says 'Installation not supported' - I see from the screenshots though, Courier is available as a fixed width font.... do you know how to access it as a CFont type? Thanks ;)

Comment: Adam, yes, I am afraid it won't work on version 3 and later phones. The SIS file only supports <= v2. I cannot at the moment tell you how to access the Courier CFont typeface, but I am playing with fonts these days. If and when I find something, I'll post back. :)